# Is there a way to transfer a rigged mesh from a new version of blender to an old one?

Tags: export, file-format, versions

This is a bit of a long shot, but I'm wondering if there's any way to get my model with the rig over from version 2.9 to version 2.7. From the googling I've done there doesn't seem to be a way to open a file created in 2.9 in 2.7, but I'm wondering if there's some other way to export it similar to exporting the mesh as an obj (although one that preserves all that hard work I did painting weights.) I'm pretty new to blender and I haven't done much rigging in the past either, so I'm out of my depth here. Thanks!

Comment: Try using the FBX export instead. Make sure to select both your mesh and rig, and select only selected in the export menu.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think you can copy and paste it between different files no matter the version number.